# Inserting Image Tags in Pre Tags

Tags: html, pre

I'm writing code examples on a web page in pre tags The problem is that when I have something like

```
<img src="foo.jpg">
```

The browser actually generates the image. How can I display image tags without an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML entities instead of angle quotes:

```
<pre>&lt;img src="foo.jpg"&gt;</pre>
```

`<pre>` tags only preserve whitespace, HTML tags within are still rendered

Comment: Is this still true ? I only see the img tag printed as text https://jsfiddle.net/remi_v/6hz7najs/